# How to point a subdomain to another "folder" on same server?

Tags: nginx, laravel-5.7, laravel-forge

So I have set up two domains with each of there repositories on one server with forge. It looks like this:

DomainA.com (179.x.x.x) 
DomainB.com (179.x.x.x)

In my DNS I have pointed them both to the same ip, and forge has handled everything else and it works great.

On the server there's two folders.
DomainA.com
DomainB.com

So now I want to create a subdomain on DomainB which "loads" the code of DomainA, example: code.domainb.com will load show the contents which in on domaina.com.

I'm not sure how I can do that? So far I understand that I need to change something in the nginx config, hopefully someone can give me some pointers :)

Nginx config for domainb:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/domainb.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name .domainb.com;
    root /home/forge/domainb.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domainb.com/471043/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domainb.com/471043/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers XXX;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/domainb.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domainb.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/domainb.com/after/*;
```

Nginx conf for domain A:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/domaina.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name .domaina.com;
    root /home/forge/domaina.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domaina.com/470443/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domaina.com/470443/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers XXX;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/domaina.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domaina.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/domaina.com/after/*;
```

Comment: Can you put an example on what your nginx conf for DomainB.com is?

Comment: I have added conf for both domains now

Comment: So you want to show domainA, without redirecting to it, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `server_name` directive can have more than one value. The exact match HOST name takes precedence. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

If `code.domainb.com` uses the same document root as the server block for `.domaina.com`, simply add its name to the `server_name` directive.

For example:

```
server {
    ...
    server_name .domainb.com;
    root /home/forge/domainb.com/public;
    ...
}
server {
    ...
    server_name .domaina.com code.domainb.com;
    root /home/forge/domaina.com/public;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) for more.